# Effervescence with NaHCO3

Tags: acid-base, solubility

How To find which organic compound gives effervescence when reacts with $\ce{NaHCO3}$? Specially in case of phenols, which one reacts and which does not? According to my professor, all acids stronger than $\ce{H2CO3}$ evolve $\ce{CO2}$ when treated with $\ce{NaHCO3}$. But I do not understand how to find which acid is stronger than $\ce{H2CO3}$, further how to find same for $\ce{Na}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$  especially when the pKa values are not given in question.

[image: How to solve this type of questions?]

Comment: You can assume that the phenols are less acidic than $\ce{H2CO3}$.

Comment: What about substituted phenols like nitro Phenols etc.?

Comment: Good point. [2,4-dinitrophenol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,4-Dinitrophenol) is a stronger acid than $\ce{H2CO3}$.

Comment: Are there many such compounds that I will have to remember or just few exceptions?

Comment: What exactly does your question look like?

Comment: I mean to say that if your are given a list of different organic compounds in test and told to find out how many of the compounds will show effervescence with NaHCO3 then what will be the approach to solve the question?

Comment: Under an examination context, I do not know what your examiner expects you to know.

Comment: Phenol having one or more nitro groups on o and p position are stronger than H2CO3 and gives effervascence with sodium bicarbonate.

Comment: Only nitro groups matter or other groups which show electron withdraw movement matter too?

Comment: Yes all electron withdrawing groups on ortho and para positions of phenol are stronger acids than phenol.

Comment: Can you please tell the answer of above match up so that I can cross check it with my answer

Comment: a)pqs b)pqrs c)pqrs d)pqrs